# Exclude interface when send ICMP ping

Tags: network-interface, ping, icmp

for build small linux application I need to check the internet connectivity of the system. But my box have multiple network interfaces with interfaced for backup internet connection. I need to do some task based on main network connection lose the connectivity.

I used to chose interface using -i with ping command

```
ping -I eth0 x.x.x.x
```

but with this method i have to mention all the available interfaces on my application. Other than doing this is there any way to do something like this

```
ping -I !bkp0 x.x.x.x
```

basically I need to check the connectivity of all the links except backup link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just need one to work to call it "good"? If you need to check the connectivity for all of the interfaces except one, and you know the name of the interface, you could script it:

```
for i in `ip -br link | cut -d" " -f1`
do
  if [ ${i} != "bkp0" ]
    then
      ping -c 1 -I ${i} so.me.add.ress
  fi
done
```